# pipe password of kinit over ssh

Tags: ssh, kerberos

***Disclaimer:*** I'm creating a quick and dirty script for my own personal use, I'm aware that this isn't the correct way to do things.

I want to initialize a kinit on a remote host (no keytab available).

When I do this locally, it works fine.

```
kdestroy; echo superstrongpassword | kinit myusername@REALM.COM
```

But I can't seem to be able to run the same thing over ssh.

```
ssh -q -tt hostname.com "kdestroy; echo superstrongpassword | kinit myusername@REALM.COM"
```

Comment: There is always the possiblity to use public key authorization to just not require passwords? Also you could add commands that require root/sudo rights to the sudoers file and use the NOPASSWD for that specific command.

Comment: I'm not the admin of these nodes, so no adding things to files allowed. It's also about the kinit, not the ssh password

Comment: Oh, well why is a keytab then not available? That would be the better solution to anything else. Try setting one up, usually with `kutil`. Like you said it's  a dirty way how you are trying to do it and that is exactly why kinit doesn't support such things.

Comment: What does not work? What errors you get? What you expect?

Comment: I expected it to "just work" like described. I ended up using a keytab in the end. But for the sake of answering this question or future reference I would still like to know how to "pipe a password to kinit over ssh"